# CGI script not running, Internal Server Error (500) Error

Tags: perl, apache, cgi, centos, internal-server-error

I am trying to run a cgi script, its a long script so i wont paste here but it works on my other servers but for some reason when I try to run it on my new server I get Internal server error (500), and when I check the apache log here is what I get :

```
[Fri Mar 30 08:38:29 2012] [error] [client 199.212.76.124] (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/test.cgi' failed
[Fri Mar 30 08:38:29 2012] [error] [client 199.212.76.124] Premature end of script headers: test.cgi
[Fri Mar 30 08:38:29 2012] [error] [client 199.212.76.124] File does not exist: /var/www/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Fri Mar 30 08:41:11 2012] [error] [client 199.212.76.124] (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/test.cgi' failed
[Fri Mar 30 08:41:11 2012] [error] [client 199.212.76.124] Premature end of script headers: test.cgi
[Fri Mar 30 08:41:11 2012] [error] [client 199.212.76.124] File does not exist: /var/www/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Fri Mar 30 08:41:12 2012] [error] [client 199.212.76.124] (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/test.cgi' failed
[Fri Mar 30 08:41:12 2012] [error] [client 199.212.76.124] Premature end of script headers: test.cgi
[Fri Mar 30 08:41:12 2012] [error] [client 199.212.76.124] File does not exist: /var/www/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Fri Mar 30 08:41:15 2012] [error] [client 199.212.76.124] (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/test.cgi' failed
[Fri Mar 30 08:41:15 2012] [error] [client 199.212.76.124] Premature end of script headers: test.cgi
[Fri Mar 30 08:41:15 2012] [error] [client 199.212.76.124] File does not exist: /var/www/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Fri Mar 30 08:41:20 2012] [error] [client 199.212.76.124] (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/upload.cgi' failed
[Fri Mar 30 08:41:20 2012] [error] [client 199.212.76.124] Premature end of script headers: upload.cgi
[Fri Mar 30 08:41:20 2012] [error] [client 199.212.76.124] File does not exist: /var/www/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Fri Mar 30 08:41:21 2012] [error] [client 199.212.76.124] (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/upload.cgi' failed
[Fri Mar 30 08:41:21 2012] [error] [client 199.212.76.124] Premature end of script headers: upload.cgi
[Fri Mar 30 08:41:21 2012] [error] [client 199.212.76.124] File does not exist: /var/www/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Fri Mar 30 08:41:29 2012] [error] [client 199.212.76.124] (2)No such file or directory: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/upload.cgi' failed, referer: http://bla.com
[Fri Mar 30 08:41:29 2012] [error] [client 199.212.76.124] Premature end of script headers: upload.cgi, referer: http://bla.com
```

I have tried everything, chmod the files, reinstall perl modules, rechecking the configuration etc!!!! Can not figure out what is wrong!!! but I can guarantee that the script is not broken!

Regards

Comment: This could be wrong path to executable. Confirm that `#!/usr/bin/perl` or whatever you have in the first line exists and is executable.

Comment: I can almost guarantee that your script is broken, if not by itself then by way of unmet dependencies. In addition to what @mcsi said, look for missing permissions, missing libraries, wrong versions, etc. Running the script from the command line might be a good way to reveal more.

Comment: Just because your script works, doesn't mean it will not throw a 500 error. For instance, if your script doesn't return a content-type to apache, it will throw that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running:

```
perl -c /var/www/cgi-bin/upload.cgi
```

Quote from perldoc perlrun:

> ```
>    -c   causes Perl to check the syntax of the program and then exit
>         without executing it.  Actually, it will execute "BEGIN",
>         "UNITCHECK", "CHECK", and "use" blocks, because these are
>         considered as occurring outside the execution of your program.
>         "INIT" and "END" blocks, however, will be skipped.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Run your script with perl -w /var/www/cgi-bin/upload.cgi.

I should write out an HTTP header

```
Content Type: text/html
[blank line]
```

If not, your script not working well. Maybe the other server pass you a variable and your script won't create a proper header any more.

Paste this code in the very to of your script. If your script looks bad, but working, you found out the bug.print("Content Type: text/html\n\n");

```
print("Content Type: text/html\n\n");
```

regards,

Answer (score 1):

Other things to check would be

- the location of perl in the first like (#!/usr/..)
- dos2unix the file, no asci characters
- other cgi scripts in different locations to eliminate cgi setup
- directory perms?  Not sure if that effects it